# Make a Button Macro That Pastes a Column of Data After my Last Column

Tags: excel, vba

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-Cnpvgoos3ceGRRZ00yYzVyUVE

Here is a book that has the document in question.

Essentially, I need help writing the code to paste the data values from "Sheet2" to the end of my data on "Sheet1".  The catch is that every time I hit the button it will paste the data one column to the right of the previously pasted data.  Every month when I make a report I just hit the button and it adds the data to the previous data.

Here is the code I have so far.

```
Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = Workbooks("VBA TEST BOOK.xlsm")

Dim lColumn As Long
    lColumn = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Columns.Count + wb.Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Columns.Count - 1
```

lColumn is supposed to represent the last column with data in it, which I would think would be the column left of the Sparklines.

My thoughts are that it would be easiest to accomplish what I am trying to do by inserting a column to the left of my Sparklines and pasting the data to it.  I'm not really sure how to use a column that has a changing location.

Can anyone help?

Comment: If you want to paste it after the last month, you mean to the right of the last column, right ?

Comment: In between the Sparklines and the Previous months data

Comment: It would have to be an inserted column in between the sparklines and the previous month's data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Figured out a solution.  I put a place holder at the end of my data.  In my example my placeholder is "X".  At the end of each row is a placeholder.  Now I can use a range that is defined as cells with "X" in them.  I can then use that range to insert a column to the immediate left of it.  Here is my code in case anyone ever looks this up for reference.  I think I have more code than is actually necessary.

```
Sub Button_Click()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim newdata As Range
Dim StartCell As Range
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastColumn As Long
Dim n As Range

    Set wb = Workbooks("VBA TEST BOOK.xlsm")

    Set newdata = wb.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B2:B8")

    Set StartCell = Cells.Find("X")

wb.Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange

LastRow = StartCell.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

LastColumn = StartCell.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column

    Set n = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(StartCell, wb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(LastRow, LastColumn))

n.Activate

ActiveCell.EntireColumn.Insert Shift:=xlToLeft, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromRightOrAbove

Dim PasteDestination As Range

    Set PasteDestination = Cells.Find("X").Offset(0, -1)

newdata.Copy

PasteDestination.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

End Sub
```

Cheers